# HOMEWORK: Minimum angle to start the mop moving

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Situation:

I'm a janitor who wants to clean the floor with a mop. I need to find a minimum angle theta so that the mop starts moving.

[image]

First, I constructed the Newton's equations:

$$ma_x = F_\text{push} \sin(\theta) - F_f$$

$$ma_y = F_n - F_g - F_\text{push}\cos(\theta)$$

Then, I set both $ma_x$ and $ma_y$ equations equal to zero and simplified the equations:

$$\mu_\text{static} F_n = F_p \sin(\theta)$$
$$F_n = mg + F_p \cos(\theta)$$

Then, I divided the equations:

$$\mu_\text{static} = \frac{F_p \sin(\theta) } { mg + F_p \cos(\theta) }$$

Then, I looked at the answer and found that $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\mu_\text{static})$. So, I assumed that $F_p$ is infinitely large and used L'Hôpital's Rule and got the right answer.

The question is: is it right to assume that $F_p \to \infty$?

Comment: You may ask your colleague from Leningrad Polytechnica. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZd8sDquNYw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving your system of equations for the force applied to the mop gives:

$$F_{p}=\frac{mg\mu_{s}}{sin(\theta)-\mu_{s}cos(\theta)}$$

By your coordinate system, we know that the force must be greater than zero, that gives us the following inequality:

$$sin(\theta) - \mu_{s}cos(\theta)\gt0$$

Manipulating that gives us:

$$\frac{sin(\theta)}{cos(\theta)}\gt \mu_{s}$$
$$tan(\theta)\gt\mu_{s}$$

Thus, the minimum angle is $\arctan{(\mu_{s})}$

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now after struggling for 1~2 hrs.

Comment: So, what happens if $\theta\le\tan^{-1}(\mu_s)$?