# A fastidious worker pushing a mop with constant force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I encountered a Homework like question. However, I am not interested in the solution as such, but rather, in a specific concept. My question is related to the following post ([HOMEWORK: Minimum angle to start the mop moving](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95238/homework-minimum-angle-to-start-the-mop-moving)), but I do not quite get how is the magnitude of the force being positive is connected to the minimum angle with which the worker must push the mop such that it starts moving. What happens for $\theta=0$, for instance? Why does all these calculations break?

Comment: At $\vartheta=0$ you are pushing straight downwards, the mop has no reason to move horizontally.

Comment: Okay, this is a limiting case. What about at small angles $\theta$?

Comment: At small angles, no matter how hard you push, friction is sufficient to counter, leading to no motion.

Comment: Okay, so, at small angles friction is sufficient to counter. But how do we recover that result from the expression we derive? Namely, that the force magnitude is $F=mg\mu_k/(\sin\theta-\mu_k\cos\theta)$?

Comment: For small angles the denominator is negative.

Comment: 1) That is no longer conceptual question, you should just work out the mathematics for it. 2) The solution in that answer is just bad. I have no intention of going with that.

Comment: Okay, let me try and elaborate a bit about my confusion: On the one hand we know that for some angle $\theta<\theta_0$ (for some angular cutoff $\theta_0$, the friction is always sufficient to cointer the force exerted by the worker. On the other hand, applying Newton's laws gives us a magnitude for the force exerted by the worker and we observe that this magnigude can be negative for some angles $\theta<\tan^{-1}(\mu_s)$. How do we know that $\theta_0=\tan^{-1}(\mu_s)$?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think you can understand that my confusion doesn't have to do with "working out the mathematics". I think I have explained a bit further my confusion now. If you have no intention of going with that, it is your right. Maybe someone else can shed some light into this

Comment: The Newtonian application does not work out a magnitude of the applied force. That is just a mistake. But the inference that $\vartheta_0=\arctan\mu_s$ is the correct and standard one; you just have to understand that it is all that you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analysis in the solution to the original PSE post is just conceptually wrong. So we have to redo it. I reserve subscripts and superscripts for tensors as much as I can, so we shall have friction $f$, weight $W$, normal reaction force $N$, and the push along the rod of the mop is $P$.
$$\text{N2L}:\qquad\sum\vec F=\frac{\mathrm d\vec p}{\mathrm dt}=m\vec a\\
\uparrow+\text{ve}:\qquad0=N-W-P\cos\vartheta\\
\rightarrow+\text{ve}:\qquad ma_x=P\sin\vartheta-f$$
The vertical force balance is obvious, and gives us
$$N=W+P\cos\vartheta$$
The analysis of the horizontal forces requires an understanding of what friction actually would be doing. When a system is experiencing static friction, then friction would be a variable, finding a specific value to cancel the attempted motion. That is, beneath the maximum possible friction $f_\text{max}=\mu_sN$, we have that
$$\exists f\in\left[0,f_\text{max}\right]\ |\qquad0=ma_x=P\sin\vartheta-f\qquad\implies\qquad P\sin\vartheta-f_\text{max}\leqslant0$$
The condition that it starts moving, of course, is the opposite inequality, $P\sin\vartheta-f_\text{max}>0$, because the friction can no longer find a magnitude big enough to oppose the attempted motion, thus actual motion happens.

Since $\mu_k\leqslant\mu_s$, for a constant force $P$ and constant angle $\vartheta$, this means that once the mop starts moving, it will keep accelerating. The above inequality is thus the conceptually correct, necessary and sufficient conditions for the mop to start moving.
$$P\sin\vartheta>f_\text{max}=\mu_sN=\mu_s(W+P\cos\vartheta)\\
P(\sin\vartheta-\mu_s\cos\vartheta)>\mu_smg$$
This is a complicated inequality to satisfy for motion to happen. Firstly, we note that $\vartheta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]\implies\left(\cos\vartheta,\sin\vartheta,\tan\vartheta\right)\in\left(\mathbb R^+_0\right)^3$ so that
$P\left(\sin\vartheta-\mu_s\cos\vartheta\right)=P\cos\vartheta\left(\tan\vartheta-\mu_s\right)$, so that we can clearly see that, if $\tan\vartheta\leqslant\mu_s$, then for $+$ve $P$, the LHS of the inequality is always $-$ve. That is, no matter how big a force $P$ you push on the mop that way, it will still always be that $P\sin\vartheta-f_\text{max}\leqslant0$ and thus there will be no motion. That is Case 1.

Case 2: If we satisfy $\tan\vartheta>\mu_s$ but $0\leqslant P\leqslant\frac{\mu_smg}{\sin\vartheta-\mu_s\cos\vartheta}$, then while we may have met the minimum sufficient angle, we do not yet have met the sufficient force for that same angle. Then, again, it will not move.

Case 3: Only by satisfying both $\tan\vartheta>\mu_s\quad\bigwedge\quad P>\frac{\mu_smg}{\sin\vartheta-\mu_s\cos\vartheta}$ will the mop start moving.

Now, if you think a little bit more about this, it will be clear that, if $P\leqslant\mu_smg$ then no angle is sufficient for motion. $\sin\vartheta-\mu_s\cos\vartheta$ is a monotonically increasing function from 0 to 1 in the interval $\vartheta\in\left(\arctan\mu_s,\frac\pi2\right]$, so that for any $P>\mu_smg$, then $\exists\vartheta_c\in\left(\arctan\mu_s,\frac\pi2\right]\ |\quad\vartheta\geqslant\vartheta_c\implies$motion

With a complete analysis like this, it should be clear that what you were confused is really about the mathematics and its wrongful application in the original solution in the original PSE post. This is why I said what I said.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answere @naturallyInconsistent. I didn't realize that we have two parameters to play with (i.e. $P$ and $\theta$) and hence three cases. Idk if this is under the umbrella of "applying the mathematics", but anyhow. Thank you so much.

Comment: The solution in the original question could be said to be applying infinite forces, and then it would be somewhat tolerable. Still, incredibly sloppy and conceptually wrong. It definitely is part of the maths---it is actually quite common for people to work out correct maths and interpret them wrongly. Just be aware of such dangers.

Answer (score 0):

> but I do not quite get how is the magnitude of the force being
> positive is connected to the minimum angle with which the worker must
> push the mop such that it starts moving.

In order for horizontal motion of the mop to be impending, the positive horizontal component of the pushing force $F$, which is $F\sin\theta$ has to equal the maximum possible static friction force, which is $\mu_{s}F\cos\theta$ (neglecting the weight of the mop). So the relationship between the angle $\theta$ and the coefficient of static friction $\mu_s$ for impending motion is

$$F\sin\theta=\mu_{s}F\cos\theta$$
$$\tan\theta=\mu_s$$

For all $\tan\theta\gt \mu_s$ friction is kinetic.

Clearly, as the angle $\theta$ gets smaller both the horizontal pushing force gets smaller and the maximum possible static friction force needed to be overcome gets greater. At $\theta=0$ there is no horizontal component of the pushing force, so no matter what the magnitude of the applied force there will be no horizontal motion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, you cannot omit the weight of the mop. It is not a difficult thing to add.

Comment: I didn’t say whether you should or shouldn’t. And I know it’s not a difficult thing  to do. Anyway, I don’t think it has anything to do with the OP’s issue .

Comment: Hi @BobD and thank you for hearing me out and for the nice reply. Okay, so what you say is understandable. From what you say, I realise that there is some angle $\theta_0$, beyond which the horizontal component of the force $F$ is greater than the static friction. Therefore, when $\theta\ge\theta_0$ the mop starts moving. The analysis one does in subquesiton a reveals that the magnitude of the force $F$ is given by the formula $F=mg\mu_k/(\sin\theta-\mu_k\cos\theta)$ when the mop is moving with a constant velocity.

Comment: Then, the post I cite states that substituting $\mu_k\rightarrow\mu_s$ allows one to study the static case (when the mop is not moving). My question is "why does demanding $F>0$ yields an expression for the minimum angle $\theta_0$ (as I defined $\theta_0$ in the previous comment)? I mean what does the fact that the magnitude of the force being zero has anything to do with the ability of the mop to move?" I hope I am making myself clear about the confusion...